# Move to text from an Image map with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to move from my image to a location on my text but it is not working 
here is the HTML code for the image

```
<img src="src" usemap="#pm84550" width="1338" height="720" alt="click   map" border="0" /><map id="pm84550" name="pm84550"><area shape="rect" alt="Geospatial Visualization" title="Geospatial Visualization" coords="294,31,1323,446" href="javascript:void(null)" target="_blank" onClick="function()" />
```

and here is the javascript code.

```
<h5 id="reg1">something</h5>

<script>
function(){

var elem = document.getElementById("reg1");
elem.on("click",function(e){
window.location = "#something";
});

}
</script>
```

I use wordpress. The problem is when I click on that part of my image I am not taken to the location on my text.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you try to use jquery:

```
function(){
    var elem = $("#reg1");
    elem.on("click",function(){
        window.location = "#something";
    });
}
```

If you dont have jquery you can do:
addEventListener("click"

```
function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("reg1")
    elem.addEventListener("click",function(){
        window.location = "#something";
    });
}
```

remember the compatibility:
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

remembet `$("#reg1")` is jquery object and `document.getElementById("reg1")` is a dom element

Comment: Thanks. I used to work with ASP and Jquery and now I am asked to work with wordpress. another problem now is that the function() of onclick in area tag is not doing anything

Comment: I think most of themes use JQuery in wordpress.

About the onclick="function()" it is a bad syntax, Don't do anything... fail and continue to execute the href